# AutoCAD: Edit object attribute table automatically

Tags: automation, attributes, label, autocad

I have several (many) objects in an AutoCAD drawing and each of them has the same attribute field in it's preferences. Now I would like to fill this attribute field with a number (object one - number 1, object two - number 2 and so on). Putting the numbers in manually is very time consuming, therefore I would like to ask you if there's an automated approach for this matter.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Solution found: ALTEXT does the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### An Example

The following program is a very simple example which will prompt you for an attribute tag to be numbered and an integer from which to start the numbering, and will then continuously prompt you to select attributed block references to be numbered, incrementing the number by one for each valid selection:

```
(defun c:attnum ( / ent enx num tag )
    (if (/= "" (setq tag (strcase (getstring "\nSpecify attribute tag <exit>: "))))
        (progn
            (setq num (cond ((getint "\nSpecify starting number <1>: ")) (1)))
            (while
                (not
                    (progn
                        (setvar 'errno 0)
                        (setq ent (car (entsel (strcat "\nSelect block number " (itoa num) " <exit>: "))))
                        (cond
                            (   (= 7 (getvar 'errno))
                                (prompt "\nMissed, try again.")
                            )
                            (   (null ent))
                            (   (/= "INSERT" (cdr (assoc 0 (setq enx (entget ent)))))
                                (prompt "\nThe selected object is not a block.")
                            )
                            (   (/= 1 (cdr (assoc 66 enx)))
                                (prompt "\nThe selected block is not attributed.")
                            )
                            (   (progn
                                    (setq ent (entnext ent)
                                          enx (entget  ent)
                                    )
                                    (while
                                        (and
                                            (= "ATTRIB" (cdr (assoc 0 enx)))
                                            (/= tag (strcase (cdr (assoc 2 enx))))
                                        )
                                        (setq ent (entnext ent)
                                              enx (entget  ent)
                                        )
                                    )
                                    (/= "ATTRIB" (cdr (assoc 0 enx)))
                                )
                                (prompt (strcat "\nThe selected block does not contain the attribute \"" tag "\"."))
                            )
                            (   (entmod (subst (cons 1 (itoa num)) (assoc 1 enx) enx))
                                (entupd ent)
                                (setq num (1+ num))
                                nil
                            )
                            (   (prompt "\nUnable to edit attribute value."))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
```

---

#### How to Load & Run the Above

- Open Windows Notepad.
- Copy & paste the above code into Notepad.
- Save the file with a filename of your choice, with the file extension `.lsp` (**ensure that `Save As Type` is set to `All Files (*.*)`**).
- Open AutoCAD to a new or existing drawing.
- Type `APPLOAD` at the AutoCAD command-line.
- Browse & select the file saved above, and click `Load` to load the program.
- Close the `APPLOAD` dialog.
- Type `ATTNUM` at the AutoCAD command-line to run the program.

Similar instructions may be found as part of my tutorial on [How to Run an AutoLISP Program](http://lee-mac.com/runlisp.html).

If you wish for the program to be automatically loaded for every new or existing drawing opened in AutoCAD, refer to my tutorial on [Loading Programs Automatically](http://lee-mac.com/autoloading.html).

---

### Other Existing Solutions

In addition to the above, you may also be interested in the following programs:

- My [Incremental Numbering Suite](http://lee-mac.com/numinc.html) application will provide a far more extensive set of options to allow you to customise the numbering format, permitting a Prefix & Suffix, multiple incrementing sections, and alphanumerical incrementing.

  You can number existing attributed block references using this application by typing 'R' or 'r' at the AutoCAD command-line during object placement to enter *Replacement Mode*.
- My [Incremental Array](http://lee-mac.com/incrementalarray.html) application will allow you to automatically increment the attribute values whilst arraying an attributed block reference (or other objects).

Comment: This is literally everything! Plain and simple but yet so effective. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This lsp helps you add a prefix or suffix to any block attribute, but to all blocks at the same time, I had a similar case like yours so I combines above attnum.lsp with this Presuf.lsp.

First use attnum to set tag field to increasing numbers 1,2,3,4,etc. Then isolate the objects and run presuf, indicate whether is a suffix or prefix to add, indicate the desired value and then select all the objects.

```
(defun c:presuf ( / as el en i ss str typ )

 (initget "Prefix Suffix")
 (setq typ (cond ((getkword "\nAdd Prefix or Suffix? [Prefix/Suffix] <Prefix>: ")) ("Prefix")))
 (setq str (getstring t (strcat typ " to Add: ")))

 (if (setq ss (ssget '((0 . "INSERT") (66 . 1))))
     (repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
         (setq en (ssname ss (setq i (1- i))))
         (while (eq "ATTRIB" (cdr (assoc 0 (setq el (entget (setq en (entnext en)))))))
             (setq as (cdr (assoc 1 el)))
             (if (eq "Prefix" typ)
                 (if (not (wcmatch as (strcat str "*")))
                     (entmod (subst (cons 1 (strcat str as)) (assoc 1 el) el))
                 )
                 (if (not (wcmatch as (strcat "*" str)))
                     (entmod (subst (cons 1 (strcat as str)) (assoc 1 el) el))
                 )
             )
         )
     )
 )
 (princ)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had the attribute tags, or block names I could take a stab at answering your question with a custom solution, however, I do believe you can find all you need [here](http://www.lee-mac.com/index.html) ([BFind](http://www.lee-mac.com/bfind.html) or [Global Attribute Extractor & Editor](http://www.lee-mac.com/macatt.html)).